# What is difference between mongo error : "E11000 duplicate key error index" AND "E11000 duplicate key error collection"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose for adding data into Mongo. But sometimes I am getting one of the "E11000 duplicate key error index" and "E11000 duplicate key error collection".
What is difference between those?

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know for sure, but i think the underlying error is the same and there is no difference.

I think the exact error wording depends on which database storage engine you use, or if you use sharding or not.

In most common use case, you should get the "key error collection" wording, but
if you have sharding enabled, or use different engine, then you can get different wording for same error.

Anyways, i dont know if this is the case, i only briefly checked the mongo source code.